# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

English Language & Usage's [fourth moderator election](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: tchrist] [image: MετάEd]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please join me in thanking [simchona](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/10893/simchona) who is stepping down.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5649233675812864/0).

Comment: Congrats, guys! I know you'll do well.

Comment: Congrats! Great choices.

Comment: Congrats. Great, right, and reasonable choices in terms of achievements, contributions to our community, knowledge and personalities.

Comment: Why doesn't tchrist's flair have the diamond while metaed's does?

Comment: @NVZ: Probably caching. I can see it [on my machine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KDljy.png).

Comment: @JonEricson, https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program/, totally brought that on yourself :P

Answer (score 26):

Welcome to our new moderators!

Farewell to simchona and thank you for your service!

And finally, a big thank you to all the candidates. It is a scary thing to put yourself out there like that and you did it! We had a lot of good choices this election and I hope you will consider running again in a future election.

Comment: Upvoted; but I thought I'd add my name explicitly to this.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Show the crew off, add your name!! Although it would be more preferable to add it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 7):

Let me congratulate you guys. We had so many good candidates and, not surprisingly, you made it in what was a keen competition.  You're both great contributors and have been around long enough for us to feel sure that your attitudes as moderators will always be tempered with reason and tolerance. Good luck.